# Need to design a formula to extract 'DE12345' from a free form text box

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula to extract DEF-678, but if DE12345 comes after it, it gets ignored.  I need to extract them both in separate boxes with their own unique formulas.

Here is the formula I have:
=IFERROR(MID(cell_number,FIND("DE",cell_number),8),"")

Is there a way to use a wild card or numerical operator to extract DE###?
Should I suck it up and learn VBA? would that make it easier?

Thanks

Comment: As you can observe, [`FIND`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) has three arguments. So to find the second DE, use `find("DE", cell, find("DE", cell) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given many details so I'm making some assumptions here:

1. Your starting string always has the `DEF-###` string **BEFORE** the `DE#####` string
2. There are not any other strings involved that have `DE`
3. String length for both is always 7 *(not sure why you are using 8?)*

---

If the above is true you can extract your first string using

```
=MID(A1,FIND("DE",A1),7)
```

And your second string using

```
=MID(A1,FIND("DE",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"DEF","~~~")),7)
```

To get the second string we can just remove the `DEF` tag from the text and then use the exact same approach taken to get the first string :)

[image]